How can I fix indentation to be consistent within table of contents (same for list of figures / tables) when numbers increase more than 10

As you can see above in the image, "Timeline" indentation is consistent with the before, however, it is not consistent with any of the after (since the number increased further more than 10). Same things happens in list of tables / list of figures.
This is a code snipet
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}

\makeatletter
% Adjust spacing in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\hspace{1em}} % Adjust 1em for space after the number

% Adjust spacing in the List of Figures
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}} % Adjust the 3em for spacing after figure number

% Adjust spacing in the List of Tables
\renewcommand{\l@table}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}} % Adjust the 3em for spacing after table number
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Purpose}
\subsubsection{Background}
\subsubsection{Objectives}
\subsubsection{Stakeholders}
\subsubsection{Project Scope}
\subsubsection{Assumptions}
\subsubsection{Constraints}
\subsubsection{Risks}
\subsubsection{Deliverables}
\subsubsection{Timeline}
\subsubsection{Success Criteria}

\end{document}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are different approaches to the table of contents, just from a screenshot we unfortunately can't help you. Please provide a minimal document including your used class and the ToC-relevant packages. You don't have to share your actual contents if you don't want to, just using a bunch of sectioning commands as the document's body would be enough.

Will do... it is just a huge document. I'll create dummy one and share it

\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\hspace{1em}} % Adjust 1em for space after the number
After commenting out the above comment, indentation is now consistent.
